# React/Redux shopping cart not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning how to build a very simple shopping cart by hand by looking at examples, and managed to get something up on my sample site with no errors. Here's the cart component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Cart extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.items.length}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Cart);
```

When someone clicks a button on another component, it's supposed to run what's in the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    items : []
}

const cartReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const newState = {...state};
    switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD_TO_CART":
            newState.items.push(action.item);
            break;
        default:
            return newState;
    }
    return newState;
}

export default cartReducer;
```

However, I'm unable to see the cart's `this.props.items.length` increase whenever I click the button, even though I can log the items array in the console and see it being added to. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? I can provide more code if necessary.

Comment: you are not returning something in the add to cart case. You sure the state is updating?

Comment: @İlker it's updating because they are mutating the state!

Answer (score 1):

Your component doesn't re-render because `this.props.items` is the same `array` as before.  You haven't actually updated your state to have a new, modified array.

What you *have* done is something that you should definitely not do, which is to mutate the existing `state`.  `newState.items` is the same `array` as `state.items` because `newState` copies all of the properties of `state`.  You cannot call `push()` on it because `push` is a mutating operation.

You need to create a copy of the `array`, either with spread syntax or with `concat()`.

```
const cartReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD_TO_CART":
            return {
                ...state,
                items: state.items.concat(action.item)
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

---

You can also use the [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) helper library which makes life easier by allowing you to write reducers with mutations.

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    items: []
  },
  reducers: {
    addToCart(state, action) {
      state.items.push(action.payload)
    },
  }
});

// action creator functions
export const { addToCart } = cartSlice.actions;

// reducer
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Wow, this shows how very little I know about JS basics. This solution worked, thank you!